# Python Function TypeError

Tags: python

I need help fixing my code error when running the code
the error is

```
"TypeError: addition() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'"
```

I need to develop a Python program to display the menu

A.  Calculate addition

B.  Calculate subtraction

C.  Calculate division

D.  Calculate multiplication

Q. Quit

Please enter your selection:

•In your program, you need to write five functions.

```
def  menu( ):    
def addition(a, b):      
def subtraction(a, b):    
def division(a, b):      
def multiplication(a, b):
```

•   Based on the selection, 
two numbers will be asked to enter from keyboard.
Executing the program, the result will be displayed.

•Program will be terminated until ‘Q’ is hit.

```
if choice=="A":
    num1=input("enter 1st number")
    num2=input("enter 2nd number")
    sum=addition("num1+num2")
    print("num1+num2")
if choice=="B":
    num1=input("enter your 1st number")
    num2=input("enter your 2nd number")
    difference=subtraction("num1-num2")
    print("difference")
if choice=="C":
    num1=input("enter your 1st number")
    num2=input("enter your 2nd number")
    quotient=division("num1/num2")
    print("quotient")
if choice=="D":
    num1=input("enter your 1st number")
    num2=input("enter your 2nd number")
    product=multiplication("num1*num2")
    print("product")
if choice=="Q":
    print("quit")`
```

Comment: you aren't calling your functions correctly, try `addition(num1,num2)` since you've defined your method as `def addition(a, b):`, also can you show your `addition()` function?

Comment: def addition (a, b):.                                                            Sum=a+b.                                                                           Return sum

Comment: are you using `sum` or `Sum`, capitalization matters, if you are using `sum` please don't as it's a keyword in Python and you are overriding it.

Comment: I am using sum with lowercase

Comment: If you use lowercase `sum`: don't do it! You're overwriting the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function. Use something like `result` or just do `return a + b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"num1+num2"*** results in only a value, which also, is a **`string`** because you're writing it between "" (quotes). **Don't** do that to anything but strings.

Your function requires two ***parameters*** (a and b), so you have to input those two parameters separated so the function can do his work, which would be to effectuate the operation.

You have to do this:

```
if choice=="A":
    num1=input("enter 1st number")
    num2=input("enter 2nd number")
    print(addition(num1,num2)) # <-- Pay attention to this line
    # we skipped the variable assignment as the function will return the value by itself.
```

Function:

```
def addition(a, b):
    sumV=a+b        # replace sum by sumV or anything else
    return sumV     # as others suggested.
```

So, this is more or less what you have right now. However, it would give the following **output**:

```
Choice: A
enter 1st number5
enter 2nd number3
53
```

This happens because you didn't specify what kind of input you were assigning to num1 and num2, so it's threating them like strings.
So, your function is actually concatenating those strings, that's why the result is 53, instead of 8.

To avoid that, change this:

```
num1=input("enter 1st number")
```

Into this:

```
num1=int(input("enter 1st number"))
# int is specifying you will receive an integer.
# change "int" to "float" if you want to use decimal values.
```

Apply that to the rest of your code and it should be working properly now :)

Correct **output**:

```
Choice: A
enter 1st number5
enter 2nd number3
8
```

Comment: # main program
def addition(a, b):
    sum=a+b
    return sum
def subtraction(a, b):
    difference=a-b
    return difference
def division(a, b):
    quotient=a/b
    return quotient
def multiplication(a, b):
    product=a*b
    return product

Comment: Alright, the problem was you didn't specify the input as an integer. I edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: it work but it repeats and doesn't execute to select another oprion

Comment: Well, that would be another question, you'd need to use a loop that allows you to keep asking the user. I'd recommend you to search about while loops and try to implement it on your code. If possible, always research before posting a question here, and please upvote or accept the answer that worked for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error has stated:

```
"TypeError: addition() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'"
```

Your mentioned that the implementation of your addition function is:

```
def addition(a,b)
    sum = a + b
    return sum
```

This function, accepts two parameters `a` and `b`.
However, when you call this function, it only accepts one parameter:

```
sum=addition("num1+num2")
```

`"num1+num2"` is a string, it is not even a variable, so it counts as one parameter.

i think you mean to pass the variables to the function, you should do

```
sum=addition(num1,num2)
```

Everything inside the quote is string, do not do that with variables. 
I bet you will run into the similar problem with rest of your function calls, so change them accordingly as well.

Comment: it works but doesn't give me the actual addition just the numbers combine and repeats

Comment: please don't override `sum` like that. at least mention to OP that op is doing something they shouldn't do

Comment: @FelipePineda case the type from string to int by doing: int(num1) int(numb2)